# How to find which event has fired on the collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I had a collection called approvals on which I had an event on sync and delete event types of collection to renderRows. check below code I need to reset the current collection based on the approval collection delete event.

```
this.approvals.on("sync delete", this.renderRows, this); 

function renderRows(model, e, event ) {
     //some code
     if (event.type == "delete") {
          this.collection.reset();
     }  
}
```

But I am getting the event as `undefined`. Can you please let me know how to get the event.type for collections

Comment: is `delete` a custom event or did you mean to use `remove`..? We might arrive on a solution based on that

Comment: delete is used to track if any thing is deleted from the collection, its not a custom.

Comment: There is no `delete` event in backbone as per [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog)

Comment: wondering whether any answers helped...

Answer (score 1):

You also have this option:

```
this.listenTo(this.approvals, 'sync', _.partial(this.renderData, 'sync'));
this.listenTo(this.approvals, 'delete', _.partial(this.renderData, 'delete'));
```

and `renderData` (or however you want to call it) gets one extra param which you're passing with the `_.partial` (curry)

```
renderData: function(eventName, collection, resp, options) {}
```

this is the method signature: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-133
`collection.trigger('sync', collection, resp, options);` delete looks the same

Looks like this as a basic example: (cant do `delete` but i can trigger `change`, just wait 5 seconds)

```
var Model1 = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
});

var View1 = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<%= eventName %> - <%= body %>'),
    initialize: function() {
        // render something as soon as possible
        this.render();

        this.model = new Model1();
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', _.partial(this.renderData, 'sync'));
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', _.partial(this.renderData, 'change'));
        this.model.fetch();

        // to test it
        setTimeout(_.bind(function(){this.model.set('body', 'it was changed')}, this), 5000);
    },
    // this is the normal sync/change function signature only with one extra param `eventName`
    // which is being `curry`'ed in
    renderData: function(eventName, model, resp, options) {
        this.$el.html(this.template({
            'eventName': eventName, 
            'body': model.get('body')
        }));
        return this;
    },  
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html('nothing to see here');
        return this;
    }
});

new View1({el: $('body').append($('<div>'))});
```

Run it here: http://jsfiddle.net/tLaLykk8/

Answer (score 0):

The event name isn't passed through unless it was specifically passed as an arg e.g. a `trigger('sync', 'sync')`. So you can either inspect the arguments (because they are different depending on the event in this case I think) - but that's a bad idea because they could change and it makes your code fragile. Your best bet is to simply split it out:

```
this.listenTo(this.approvals, "sync", this.onApprovalSync);
this.listenTo(this.approvals, "delete", this.onApprovalDelete);

onApprovalSync: function() {
  this.renderRows();
}

onApprovalDelete: function() {
  this.collection.reset();
  this.renderRows();
}
```

Comment: I want to use same function for both the events and most of the code is common and need to check it with event type.

Comment: You can put your common code in another method, the only other way is to check argument types but `delete` is a custom event right? so we can't help you as we don't know what the trigger signature is..

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want to have a common handler for `sync` and `remove`  events and wants to identify which event triggered the handler.

Since the signature of the callbacks of these events are different:

`remove: (model, collection, options)`
and `sync: (model_or_collection, resp, options)`

We can achieve this by checking the type of arguments passed to the handler as shown below:

```js
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.dosomething);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'remove', this.dosomething);

    this.render();
  },
  events: {
    'click #remove': 'triggerRemove',
    'click #sync': 'triggerSync',
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html('<button id="remove">Trigger remove</button><button id="sync">trigger sync</button>').appendTo('body');
    return this;
  },
  triggerRemove: function() {
    var model = this.collection.add({
      name: 'test'
    });
    this.collection.remove(model);
  },
  triggerSync: function() {
   this.collection.trigger('sync');
  },
  dosomething: function(model) {
    if (arguments[1] instanceof Backbone.Collection) //second argument is a collection
      console.log('remove triggered')
    else
      console.log('sync triggered')
  }
});
var view = new View({
  collection: new Backbone.Collection([{
    name: 'hi'
  }, {
    name: 'hellow'
  }])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```